# RStudio re-installs R 3.3.2 instead of defaulting to R 4.0.2

Tags: r, windows, installation, rstudio, version

I recently updated R to 4.0.2 on my Windows machine. After doing so, I uninstalled R 3.3.2.

Oddly, when I opened RStudio it re-installed R 3.3.2 and ran that older version instead of using the newer R 4.0.2. I thought RStudio might need to be updated, so I did that and again uninstalled R 3.3.2. This seemed to work. RStudio opened with R 4.0.2 and I could open and close RStudio and keep getting R 4.0.2.

But now RStudio has reinstalled R 3.3.2 *again* and I have to force it to select 4.0.2 by holding the CTRL key during launch. Clearly I'm missing something, and it's probably simple, but I've not run into this before. Anyone have a suggestion?

Thanks,
Laila

Comment: Are you periodically working in a specific project folder in which this occurs? Does this project have a `./packrat/` or `./renv/` directory? It might be that the project has a "requirement" for a particular version of R that rstudio is attempting to honor/enforce.

Comment: Great suggestion, but it was not part of a project. I'll keep an eye out for that

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the following? go to the 'Tools' tab, then 'General' and change the version of R (choose the R-4.0.2 folder)

Comment: Thanks for directing me there. I did just now open RStudio and without interference it opened to R 4.0.2. My Global options in the Tools tab does show it running from that folder. I've tried uninstalling R 3.3.2 again. Hopefully it holds